# Lock variables in Script Task using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm running a SQL Server Agent Job which has a script task with Microsoft Visual C# 2008 which is below:

```
public void Main()
{
        string filepath;
        filepath = Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString();
        Dts.Variables["User::FileExistsFlg"].Value = File.Exists(filepath);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

I get this error:

> Executed as user: PSFACAMDWHSQL1\SYSTEM.
>   Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
>   Version 10.50.4270.0 for 64-bit
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.
>   Started: 18:06:19
>   Error: 2015-02-27 18:07:44.95
>   Code: 0xC001404F
>   Source: For Loop Container
>   Description: This Variables collection has already been unlocked. The Unlock method is called only once on a dispensed Variables collection. End Error
>
> DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
>   Started: 18:06:19
>   Finished: 18:07:45
>   Elapsed: 85.613 seconds.
>   The package execution failed. The step failed.

I am not sure how to unlock the variable within the script task.

**UPDATE:**
I have tried this method but I am missing something on the code:

```
  public void Main()
    {


        // Lock variables
        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::FolderPath");
        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::FileExistsFlg");

        // Create a variables 'container' to store variables
        Variables vars = null;

        // Add variables from the VariableDispenser to the variables 'container'
        Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref vars);

        string filepath;
        filepath = Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString();
        Dts.Variables["User::FileExistsFlg"].Value = File.Exists(filepath);

        // Release the locks
        vars.Unlock();

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
}
```

Comment: where exactly in your package is this script task and what is the scope of the variable that you are setting.

Comment: Hi @SFrejofsky. I copied the process in http://sqlage.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/ssis-how-to-check-if-file-exists-in.html which detects a file and then runs the SSIS. I hope this helps.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Do you get that error before or after the updated code? I would say that you should not try to lock/unlock variables in code...stick to using the ReadOnlyVariables and ReadWriteVariables on the script properties.

Comment: @ dotjoe I only use the ReadOnlyVariables and ReadWriteVariables on the script task. How would you suggest I unlock the variables? I usually get the error when the SQL Server Job fails when I check the History.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your bool to an int.

```
Dts.Variables["User::FileExistsFlg"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(File.Exists(filepath));
```

Comment: That fails. I get this error when I run the Job.  Description: The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::FileExistsFlg" differs from the current variable type. Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.

Comment: And "User::FileExistsFlg" is Int32, like the article link you provided shows?

Comment: @ Sorrell I still get the same problem when I tried your solution.